# how to show tooltip when hovering?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I defined my bootstrap tooltip like this:

```
 <button popover-template="myPopoverTemplate.html" data-trigger="hover" popover-title="{{dynamicPopover.title}}" class="btn btn-default">Popover With Template</button>
```

my template looks like this:

```
<div>{{dynamicPopover.content}}</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Popup Title:</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="dynamicPopover.title" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Problem is the tooltip does not showup on hover?

plunkr ref:http://plnkr.co/edit/G1Cet74mVCkVYvdXRxnX?p=preview

Answer (score 14, accepted):

@Leeuwtje, in the plunkr reference that you have attached, there is a popover that is opening on mouseenter event (when you hover the mouse over the button).

The attribute to do that is not `data-trigger="hover"`, but `popover-trigger="mouseenter"`.

Also, for the template `popover-template="dynamicPopover.templateUrl"` is added as an attribute to the element that triggers it.

Also, if you need to prefix the attributes with `data-`, do them like this:

```
<button data-popover-template="" data-popover-trigger="" /></button>
```

The `popover` prefixed to `-template` or `-trigger` in `popover-trigger` and `popover-template` makes it an angular ui directive, so removing `popover-` would make it invalid / meaningless to angular ui.

**EDIT**

The reason the `popover-template` did not work is because it expects a variable as the attribute value.

Replacing :

```
popover-template="myPopovertemplate.html"
```

by

```
popover-template="'myPopovertemplate.html'"
```

Adding the filename in quotes does the trick.

We put the template url in single quotes so it becomes a valid variable. That is why the other buttons on the page in the plunk function, because they have the `popover-template` value to be variables that are defined in `$scope`.

**PLUNK** : http://plnkr.co/edit/oEA5ekXDV5DSw6yoSHMd?p=preview

Hope this helped!

Comment: appreciate the effort but when I hover still does not display :( Changed the plunkr slightly:http://plnkr.co/edit/G1Cet74mVCkVYvdXRxnX?p=preview

Comment: @Leeuwtje You want the template to be 'myPopoverTemplate.html' right?

Comment: @Leeuwtje Sorry I did not realize the requirement, added edits and a new Plunk, hope it helps!