# md tooltip show from controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have got a tooltip associated to a paragraph which is hidden currently and i want to show it after an event occurs in my controller.

My html code is -

```
  <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl as ctrl" layout="column" ng-cloak>
    <p>Use <code>md-autocomplete</code> to search for matches from local or remote data sources.
      <md-tooltip hide md-direction="left">
        Refresh
      </md-tooltip>     
    </p>  
  </div>
```

My controller code is -

```
  angular
  .module('starterApp')
  .controller('DemoCtrl', DemoCtrl);


function DemoCtrl($mdDialog,$mdToast) {
    var self = this;
    //I want to show the tooltip from here.
    //if(event) mdTooltip.show()


  }
```

This question is not a duplicate of [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31333038/how-to-show-tooltip-when-hovering) because i do not have a trigger such as data-trigger="hover". The trigger will come from within the controller on basis of another event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to show tooltip when hovering?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31333038/how-to-show-tooltip-when-hovering)

Comment: @DurgpalSingh that question did not help . Have added reason in edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using md-tooltip `md-visible` attribute. See documentation [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdTooltip).

Set your tooltip as follows:

```
<p>Use <code>md-autocomplete</code> to search for matches from local or remote data sources.
  <md-tooltip ng-if="showTooltip" md-visible="showTooltip" md-direction="left">
    Refresh
  </md-tooltip>     
</p>
```

> You can see a working plunker
>   [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGPbxr).

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I would create a method in the controller that sets a value say showTooltip. When the event triggers it sets showToottip to true/false. Then show/hide the tooltip using ng-show="showTooltip"

```
angular
    .module('starterApp')
    .controller('DemoCtrl', DemoCtrl);


function DemoCtrl($mdDialog, $mdToast) {
    var self = this;
    //I want to show the tooltip from here.
    //if(event) mdTooltip.show()

    self.showTooltip = false;

    self.changeTooltipStatus = function (status) {
        self.showTooltip = status
    }
}
```

Then in your HTML do something like this

```
<md-tooltip ng-show="showTooltip" md-direction="left">
    Refresh
</md-tooltip>
```